# What do I do about "batch recursion exceeds stack limits" when running Boost.Build?

Tags: c++, boost-build

I am using 64-bit Win 7.

I downloaded the latest Boost source and in order to gather binaries I have to pass trough
Boost.Build process. I took also the latest Boost.Build from official website and when I 
ran `./bootstrap` I got an error:

```
******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=592, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
```

I have i5, 8 GB of memory.

Is there some other way to gain binaries for boost for GCC (G++). I know that there is
Boostpro, but that can only give me VS binaries.

Answer (score 2):

The answer has already given by Jesse Good and DevSolar

but needs some combination

for Windows + MinGW (gcc)

1) in CMD, under the root directory of Boost, type

```
.\bootstrap.bat gcc
```

the gcc argument will stop the Recursion Error

2) then b2 will be generated in the same directory

the simplest way to install is

```
.\b2 toolset=gcc --prefix="path\of\compiled\files\" install
```

the toolset=gcc argument is necessary, otherwise compiling of .dll will fail

3) add

```
"path\of\compiled\files\include\boost_?_??"
"path\of\compiled\files\lib"
```

to system path (you may google "add system path variable win", Win 7 needs NO reboot to activate the setting )

Comment: using ".\bootstrap.bat gcc" solved the recursion problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when:

- you are using the sources from the `*.tar.bz2` package for a Windows build, **and**
- you are not specifying a toolset.

**Either** using the `*.zip` source package **or** specifying the toolset (`bootstrap.sh msvc` or whatever) resolves this problem (for me, at least).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `tools\build\v2\` in the boost directory and run the bootstrap from there.
2. Run `b2 toolset=gcc install --prefix=PREFIX` from the same directory as above where PREFIX is where you want boost.build to be installed.
3. Add `PREFIX\bin` to your PATH environment variable, and then from the boost root directory type something like the following (this is an example, change the options as you wish, to find a list of the options, type `b2 --help`):

> b2 toolset=gcc address-model=64 variant=release link=static,shared
>   threading=multi --layout=system target-os=windows

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when the `Boost` version is outdated and does not support the current toolset. For example, boost-1.57.0 does not support the VC15 compiler, and gave me your error message.

The simple solution was to use the most recent version of `Boost`.