# Boost 1.51.0 and Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

So, I have to ask very noobish question, but I have been scrambling all over the Internet and I can't seem to find the anwser.

So, I decided to use Boost with Code::Blocks. I used BoostPro Installer and installed the latest version, which is 1.51.0.

So, directory where my Boost folder is located is :

```
C:/Program files/boost
```

That directory also contains one folder within it, so it's like this :

```
C:/Program files/boost/boost_1_51
```

So, my question is, how do setup my Code::Blocks so it can work. I did the following :

Went to Settings > Global Variables, created a new one called boost.

Set it's base to : C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51

Set it's include to : C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost

Then, I went to my project, right-clicked it > Build Options > highlighted my root project > Search Directories.

Then, under my Compiler sub-tab, I clicked Add and added this :

```
$(#boost.include)
```

Under Linker sub-tab, I clicked Add and added this :

```
$(#boost.lib)
```

And I can't seem to compile sample code (located on official Boost web-site > Getting started).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't BoostPro Installer only provide VC++ binaries? Are you using VC++ with code blocks? If not, it won't work.

Comment: OK, so what do I have to do now?

Comment: Download the boost source and build it with the compiler you are using yourself.

Comment: OK, just to ask, how to do it?

Comment: Read the [getting started page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/index.html), I also provided an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484894/what-do-i-do-about-batch-recursion-exceeds-stack-limits-when-running-boost-bui/12485075#12485075). Code blocks also has a [tutorial here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef).

Comment: Also, you could use [this mingw distro here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) which comes with boost setup for you if you want, but building it yourself is always good to learn.

Answer (score 2):

The CodeBlocks wiki has instructions on setting up boost: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef

In particular, for building boost from source, look at the **Build Boost** section and make sure to choose the correct toolset (in your case, I assume it would be `--toolset=gcc` when using MinGW).

Comment: ah - didn't notice your comment @Jesse Good

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Filesystem, I used another computer, and performed the following steps, and it worked:

```
1) Installed MinGW
2) Added this enviroment variable => C:\MinGW\bin
3) bootstrap.bat gcc
4) b2 install --prefix="C:\Boostbuild" --toolset=gcc
5) Added this enviroment variable => C:\Boostbuild\bin
6) b2 --build-dir="C:\Boostbuild" toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage
7) Installed CodeBlocks without MinGW
CodeBlocks:
8) Settings->Global variables: current variable => boost, Base => C:\boost_1_53_0, include => C:\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib
9) On the new C++ console project:
Build Options->Choose Project Name on the left -> search directories
On compiler tab, press Add and type: $(#boost)
On linker tab, press Add and type: $(#boost.lib)
10) On the new C++ console project:
Build Options->Choose Project Name on the left -> linker settings
Add the following link libraries:
..\..\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-1_53.a
..\..\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw46-mt-1_53.a
```

Thanks everybody